GLMERTREE - correct usage of cluster and ranefstart arguments
Goal of analysis
I would like to evaluate the effect of meteorological and landscape variables on insect counts over time (5 sampling sessions considered here as one factor). My objective is to see whether my weather and landscape variables lead to different trajectories for my counts over time (see figure on the left).
My data are hierarchical, in that insects are captured at a total of 80 sites which are organized spatially by landscape window (=Maille). Each Maille comprises 4 sites. And each site is monitored (pseudoreplicated) over 5 sessions. I therefore have a total of 400 observations, which are not independent (see figure on the right).
My response variable (count) is unique for each observation, but my predictor variables (climate and landscape) are measured at the grid cell level and are identical for the 5 sampling sessions (in other words, my predictor variables have the same value for all the sites in the same grid cell and for all 5 sessions).

My main questions related to the error
My initial model is as follows
tree_AD <- glmertree(round(AD)  ~  Session | (1|Maille/Maille_site) | Aut21_moy_Tx_court+Hiv21_moy_Tn+Ptps22_moy_Tn+Ptps22_moy_Tx, data = A, alpha = 0.05,bonferroni=TRUE, family=poisson)
plot(tree_AD, which = "tree")


However, I'm wondering whether I need to add the arguments cluster = ?? and ranefstrat=TRUE to my model.
In the case of the cluster argument, I don't know whether I should indicate cluster=Session, cluster=Maille or cluster=Site (or a combination of the three? but in this case I don't know how to write it).I'm thinking of including Maille (because all my predictive variables are calculated by Maille, i.e. the same value for all observations in the same Maille, whatever the session). Isn't this redundant with writing my random effect (1|Maille/Maille_site)?
I tried with cluster=Maille and/or with ranefstart=T:
tree_AD <- glmertree(round(AD)  ~  Session | (1|Maille/Maille_site) | Aut21_moy_Tx_court+Hiv21_moy_Tn+Ptps22_moy_Tn+Ptps22_moy_Tx, data = A,cluster=Maille,ranefstart = T, alpha = 0.05,bonferroni=TRUE, family=poisson)
plot(tree_AD, which = "tree")

... but this systematically gives me NULL or very unstable tree (using stabletree())
In addition, when I used cluster=site I obtain an error message:
Error in chol.default(meat) : 
  the leading minor of order 6 is not positive definite
Error in chol.default(meat) : 
  the leading minor of order 5 is not positive definite
Error in chol.default(meat) : 
  the leading minor of order 5 is not positive definite
Error in root.matrix(switch(vcov, opg = chol2inv(chol(meat)), info = bread,  : 
  Matrix is not positive semidefinite

How do I manage the error message? What does this error message mean?
However, despite this error message, the function runs and I get a NULL tree.
The most stable (and non-NULL) trees are obtained either with cluster=session or without cluster.
Could you tell me the best formulation for random effects, use of cluster and ranefstart given my data structure? Should I combine my random effect specification + cluster=Maille or Site or Session + ranefstart=TRUE?

If you need advice on exactly what statistical model to use for your data, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.
